# Requesting Administrator privileges during runtime

Tags: windows, winapi, elevation

How do I request Administrator privileges during runtime so the user is given the prompt to allow or disallow it?

Comment: Is not it belongs to SuperUser ?

Comment: @hsz: not quite, as OP is looking to do this in his programs using code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is written in the exe file manifest. You must use the `requestedExecutionLevel` field (but not sure about that - try setting it to `highestAvailable` and see if it does what you need). See for example here for more information (somewhat older article but still valid): [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150717123401/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/09/08/exploring-manifests-part-2-default-namespaces-and-uac-manifests-in-windows-vista.aspx)

There are tools in Visual Studio which allow you to embed your own manifest or even just edit it. Also there is a tool written in Perl ( http://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Exe::Manifest ).

EDIT: see this article for more info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66259/Requesting-Admin-Approval-at-Application-Start.aspx

Comment: I don't always need elevated privs; I want to request it when the user clicks a button.

Comment: Oh i see, then my edit is probably irelevant. Leaving the answer here as somebody might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

if you want it in response to a button (eg, like 'show processes for all users' in task manager), you have to resart your app using the following method

```
ShellExecute(0,L"runas",exepath,0,0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change execution level during runtime; my solution was indeed to restart the application with elevation. Thanks.