# How to elevate Perl process using UAC

Tags: windows, perl, uac, elevation

Suppose I have a script that needs to read information from places that normal user is not permitted to read (e.g. other users' folders).

Currently all I can do is complain about not being run as a "superuser" and quit, but I would rather like the script to ask for elevation itself.

Comment: The simplest solution might be to create a shortcut for your script and setting the shortcut to run the process as Administrator.

Comment: @ikegami I believe this is equivalent to right-clicking and choosing "Run as administrator".  Unfortunately this menu option is missing for Perl scripts, as well as shortcuts for them, where the relevant checkbox you are apparently referring to, is *disabled*.

Comment: It's just a matter of specifying `perl.exe` as the program to run. Pass your script as an argument. (tested)

Comment: @ikegami I'm not exactly sure if this is what you mean, but I'm using Strawberry Perl (`/passive` installation), which automatically assigns *.p` files to be run with perl.exe upon double-click (or calling their name from command line).  So this has already been done by installer.

Comment: No, don't use the association. Like you said, that doesn't work. You need to provide an executable to use RunAs

Comment: @ikegami Oh, now I get it.  That works great!  I think you should post it as answer. (...although it's actually a work-around, as the script does not ask for permissions itself as I originally specified and am still very curious about :))

Comment: It should popup a UAC dialog. Are you saying it doesn't?! (Already posted it as an answer.)

Comment: @ikegami No, I meant that it does not do the job itself but actually relies on .lnk file and explorer.exe.  So deploying this script takes an extra effort of creating that .lnk.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) and [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=935549), you can try:

```
Win32::FileOp::ShellExecute( runas => 'yourprogram.exe' )
```

or

```
Win32::FileOp::ShellExecute( runasuser => 'yourprogram.exe' )
```

These should (not tested) ask you for elevation when it is needed. (Works on Windows 7 only).

Related: [Requesting Administrator privileges during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405319/how-do-i-request-admin-privs)

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with launching through a shortcut, you can use the following:

1. Create a shortcut to perl.exe
2. Edit the shortcut.

   1. On the Shortcut tab, change "Target" to

      "c:...\bin\perl.exe" "c:...\script.pl"
   2. [Optional] On the Shortcut tab, change "Start in" to the path of the directory in which your script resides.
   3. On the Shortcut tab, click "Advanced", then check "Run as Administrator".

There's a tool called "`runas`", but I can't seem to get it to work without asking you for Administrator's password.

Answer (score 2):

Tired of having no good answer to this question in my own work, I wrote [Win32::RunAsAdmin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32%3a%3aRunAsAdmin). All it does is call the Windows Shell via OLE with "runas" as the verb, but it packages it conveniently so all you have to do is stick the following at the beginning of your code:

```
use Win32::RunAsAdmin qw(force);
```

During the import step, it will check for elevated privileges, and return silently if you're already running in elevated mode. Otherwise, it restarts the script in elevated mode with a UAC popup.