# Get admin access in perl script for Win-7

Tags: perl, windows-7

Is there any method to get admin access in Win-7 while running the perl script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to elevate Perl process using UAC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019571/how-to-elevate-perl-process-using-uac)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind running the whole script as administrator, you can use the shell "runas" command:

```
runas /profile /env /user:mydomain\admin "perl myscript.pl"
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get admin access in runtime (i.e in the myscript.pl)