# How to open command prompt in Administrator mode in Perl

Tags: windows, perl, command-prompt, perl-module

I need to run a command on command prompt as an Administrator. When I usually use the system() command to send a command to run in the command prompt, I do not have Administrator level elevation.

How can I obtain Admin level privileges to run my instructions?

I am able to right click on cmd.exe and select 'Run as Administrator' to open command prompt manually in Admin mode.

Thanks!

#### Edit

I am trying to install 7-Zip if 7-Zip is not installed. *(You will need 'wget' command installed (*from Cygwin or GnuWin32) to run the snip below)*

```
use Cwd;
use File::Spec;
my $cwd = getcwd();
my $winpath = File::Spec->catdir($cwd);


if (!(-e "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip")){
    print "\n 7-Zip is not installed. Downloading ... \n";
    system("wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sevenzip/7-Zip/9.20/7z920.exe?r=&ts=1392082197&use_mirror=softlayer-dal");   # SourceForge Mirror
    print "\n Installing.. \n\n";
    #print "\n Press \"install\" to install the 7-Zip installer on your pC\n\n";
    if(-e $winpath."\\7z920.exe"){
        system($winpath."\\7z920.exe");
    }
}
```

Comment: That way of checking for 7-Zip is a little brittle - what if it was installed somewhere else? A more robust way is to search for it in PATH.

Comment: [Might be relevant, but not sure if duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019571/how-to-elevate-perl-process-using-uac)

Comment: Even more robustly, if you want zipping functionality, there are libraries like `Archive::Zip` - see https://metacpan.org/search?q=zip

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run `cmd` as Administrator, then you can run your Perl script from that instance of `cmd`, and it will inherit the Administrator privilege.

You can test by, for instance, creating a directory under `c:\windows`:

```
use strict;

if (mkdir 'c:/windows/perltest/') {
    print "We have admin permissions";
    rmdir 'c:/windows/perltest/'
} else {
    print "No admin permission"
}
```

If you are run without admin privileges and want to elevate them, check [How to elevate Perl process using UAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019571/how-to-elevate-perl-process-using-uac).

Side note: you may be able to skip downloading 7-Zip. Perl has [many libraries that can handle zipping and unzipping](https://metacpan.org/search?q=zip).

Answer (score 0):

I found a neat little utility called elevate.exe.

its pretty awesome. I am now able to send/execute commands with admin privileges.

http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/

Thanks anyway.

(please be very careful when you use this, it can be used to harm machines, and may break your system. )